# Update method with Collection::add and Collection::remove

Tags: java, java-8

In my project there is need in 2 methods: one for addition *version* to object, another for removing it.
Logic for these 2 methods is almost the same: validate conditions and if all is ok, add/remove version to issue's version `Collection`.
I have some problems with using `Collectiion::add` and `Collection::remove`, that's why I created 2 static methods `removeVersion` and `addVersion` to it. How can I update this method, so there would be no need in `FixVersionServiceImpl::addVersion` and `FixVersionServiceImpl::removeVersion`, where FixVersionServiceImpl - current class name?

```
private boolean updateIssueVersion(User user,
                                       IssuesVersionUpdateDescription issueVersionUpdate,
                                       Version version,
                                       BiFunction<Version, Collection<Version>, Boolean> function) {
        boolean updated = false;
        for (String issueKey : issueVersionUpdate.getIssueKeys()) {
            IssueService.IssueResult issueResult = issueService.getIssue(user, issueKey);
            MutableIssue issue = issueResult.getIssue();
            if (issue == null) {
                LOG.info("Issue was not found for user.");
                continue;
            }

            if (issue.getProjectObject() == null
                || !issue.getProjectObject().getKey().equals(version.getProject().getKey())) {
                LOG.error("Issue project doesn't contain this fix version.");
                continue;
            }
            Collection<Version> fixVersions = issue.getFixVersions();
            function.apply(version, fixVersions);
            issue.setFixVersions(fixVersions);
            issueManager.updateIssue(user, issue, EventDispatchOption.ISSUE_UPDATED, false);
            updated = true;
        }
        return updated;
    }

    private static boolean addVersion(Version version, Collection<Version> fixVersions) {
        return fixVersions.add(version);
    }

    private static boolean removeVersion(Version version, Collection<Version> fixVersions) {
        return fixVersions.remove(version);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collection::add` and `::remove` are of type `BiFunction<Collection<T>, T, Boolean>`, where first type refers to enclosing collection instance. So to pass those methods as argument and use them as lambda, like:

```
function.apply(fixVersions, version);
```

you need to change the type of that argument to `BiFunction<Collection<Version>, Version, Boolean>`.